# Click an element in jqgrid and select the row it is in

Tags: jqgrid

When you click on a row in jqgrid it gets "selected" (applies some coloring and styles), other "selected" rows get deselected. However, when I click on an input button element in one of the cells in a row nothing happens... the row is not "selected". How would I make the clicking of this button (or link or whatever) cause the row to be "selected" (and deselected when a different row is clicked)?

---

Solution:

In the `gridComplete` method of jqgrid I can attach a click handler to each button, get the ID of the button's parent row and then call jqgrid's `setSelection` method on it, passing in the required row id as a parameter.

```
$('#mygrid').find('input[type=button]').each(function() {
                    $(this).click(function(){
                        var therowid = $(this).parents('tr:last').attr('id');
                        $('#mygrid').jqGrid('setSelection', therowid );
                    });
                });
```

On "tricky" thing about this is that instruction on the jqgrid website show two different ways to go about doing this. The above uses the new API which does things rather differently so you will find a mix of suggestions online that switch between this new API and the older one.

Comment: Do you mean clicking on the disabled checkboxes?

Comment: @Oleg - No checkboxes. I have a button in one cell of each row in my grid that will, amongst other things, call the saveRow method when clicked. However, clicking it does not trigger the "selected" state of the row. Clicking anywhere else in the row will add a class `ui-state-highlight` to the row but clicking the button will not cause this class to be added. It looks like there is some sort of selected row trigger, applied when you click anywhere in the row, that is not being applied when you click this button.

Comment: If would be better if you would post some code and not only the description what will be done. The problem is that the solution can hard depend on your current implementation. Do you have any `click` event handle? What is the code of the handler? I am sure that there are very simple solution of you problem, but to give you any suggestion I need have much more information about your current implementation details.

Comment: @Oleg - Thanks for your assistance. I have found a solution and it is quite simple, just didn't know about it. In `gridComplete` I find each button in the grid and attach a click handler to it. I then grab the ID of the parent table row and call `setSelection` on it.